# Nested JSON with Pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to create a data frame from the JSON file below. I have been using `d1 = pd.read_json('user.json')`, but this isn't creating columns for the nested values `accessToken,facebookId` etc.

Is there an easy way of telling pandas to deal with these nested values?

This question has been asked elsewhere but I require the nested values to be input as columns in the larger dataframe.

```
{
"_id": 11,
"claimToFame": "Send me some tunes...or your GitHub!",
"commentCount": 230,
"coverImage": "img.jpg",
"currentLanguage": "en-GB",
"dateOfBirth": "07/29/1982",
"email": "l@gmail.com",
"facebookDetails":    {
        "accessToken": "123",
        "facebookId": "123"
    }
,
"facebookId": 1,
"firstName": "David",
"followerCount": 422403,
"following": false,
"followingCount": 253,
"googleDetails": 
    {
        "googleId": "111411986454983058357",
        "accessToken": "123"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way:

```
import pandas as pd
import json

data = json.dumps([{
"_id": 11,
"claimToFame": "Send me some tunes...or your GitHub!",
"commentCount": 230,
"coverImage": "img.jpg",
"currentLanguage": "en-GB",
"dateOfBirth": "07/29/1982",
"email": "l@gmail.com",
"facebookDetails":    {
        "accessToken": "123",
        "facebookId": "123"
    }
,
"facebookId": 1,
"firstName": "David",
"followerCount": 422403,
"following": False,
"followingCount": 253,
"googleDetails": 
    {
        "googleId": "111411986454983058357",
        "accessToken": "123"
    }
}], separators=(',',':'))

pd.read_json(data)
```

Comment: Hi this works quite well after further testing but could you help me with one thing. For example the facebookDteails column now contains: "{
        "accessToken": "123",
        "facebookId": "123"
    }"    Is there any way to get accessToken and facebookId in their own column?

Answer (score 0):

With your data in a file object `FILEOBJECT`, load the data into a python structure using the json module

```
import json
jsondata = json.load(FILEOBJECT)
```

you can then create the dataframe by using the json_normalize function

```
import pandas as pd
usable_dataframe = pd.io.json.json_normalize(jsondata)
```

which in your case will result in a dataframe of these columns:

[_id, claimToFame, commentCount, coverImage, currentLanguage, dateOfBirth, email, facebookDetails.accessToken, facebookDetails.facebookId, facebookId, firstName, followerCount, following, followingCount, googleDetails.accessToken, googleDetails.googleId]